# how can I group rows by col1 but sort the the rows by col2?

Tags: python, pandas

for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'col2': [3, 1, 2, 4, 3],
                   'col3': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]})
```

I want it like follow:

```
   col1 col2    col3
1   B   1   20
3   B   4   40
0   A   3   10
2   A   2   30
4   C   3   50
```

`df.sort_values(['col1', 'col2'])`

```
col1    col2    col3
2   A   2   30
0   A   3   10
1   B   1   20
3   B   4   40
4   C   3   50
```

`df.sort_values(['col2', 'col1'])`

```
col1    col2    col3
1   B   1   20
2   A   2   30
0   A   3   10
4   C   3   50
3   B   4   40
```

Then only way i found is very ugly:

```
df['min_col2'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('min')
df.sort_values("min_col2").drop("min_col2", axis="columns")
```

What is the canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to set up a temporary column if you use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) and [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
out = df.iloc[np.argsort(df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('min'))]
```

If you need this in a pipeline (chained commands):

```
out = df.iloc[lambda d: np.argsort(d.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('min'))]
```

Or a hacky way which relies on a side effect (i.e. cannot be used in a pipeline):

```
out = df.sort_values(by='col2',
                     key=lambda s: s.groupby(df['col1']).transform('min'))
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2  col3
1    B     1    20
3    B     4    40
0    A     3    10
2    A     2    30
4    C     3    50
```